# Self-Submitting form in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I would like to know the best way to "submit" a form to another page in my web app. I currently have a form where the user fills out his/her info, then upon "Submit" a new page is loaded with all of their data so that they can review it.
The user then can return to the form to make edits or accept the data and continue.

Currently, I have the form set to POST to the "next" page. I am using jQuery mobile so this is all in a single HTML file and the "pages" are just DIV's that are being shown and hidden. I intercept the "submit" event and do my processing then return false. This works, but sometimes feels glitchy.

Is it possible to POST to another jQuery mobile "page" and intercept the incoming data instead of having to return false on the submit event?
Is there another way to do this that I'm not even realizing?

I should note that a requirement of the application is that no data is allowed to be stored on the device (no Cookies, LocalStorage, SessionStorage, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage for that. When the user submit the form, use javascript to get all the data and store them in localStorage so that you can re-use them in any page with no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no data is allowed to be stored on the device (except JavaScript object literals). So no cookies, localstorage, etc.

Comment: Since you are using single page architecture, why not just save them in a javascript object/variable? In your case, when the "page" is changed, the javascript is not reloaded, thus it keep all the variables intact.

Comment: That is actually what I'm doing right now. It just seems that it is somewhat glitchy. For example, if the form doesn't validate, the "Submit" button remains depressed and the user has to tap it twice to fire the "submit" event. I am assuming this is because I am returning "false" on the submit event handler???